# How to check whether specific string exists in a comma separated MySQL field

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL field of authors in a comma separated string and i want to search for an exact match within it. For example, i want to return all the rows where 'Jeff' is a coauthor in the following table:

| test | co_authors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | jeff,beth,ben,jim |
| 2 | beth,jeffrey,benjamin, jimmothy |
| 3 | ben,beth,jim,jeff |
| 4 | ben,beth,jeffrey |

In this example, i would want to return only rows 1 and 3 - so ignoring "jeffrey" which has "jeff" as a substring.

Ideally i would return this via SQLAlchemy .filter syntax since i am using an ORM but the SQL query would also really help me.

Comment: possibly helpful : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=regexp#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.regexp_match

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in MySQL.

`SELECT * FROM authors WHERE FIND_IN_SET('jeff', co_authors) > 0;`

Hopefully, this will help you.